# Mono on OSX returns a path for a symlink instead of the real folder when asking for the current user's TMP folder

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono

I'm running a simple test here with an FSEvents based file system watcher and I have noticed that this code:

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

Will return a path under `/var/folders/something-here`. But when I setup the file system watcher all events are sent for folders at `/private/var/folders/something-here` (which is the right path, since `/var` is a symlink for `/private/var`).

Is there a way for me to tell mono to give me the real and not the symlinked path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up hacking `maccore` on Mono and created [a pull request with the changes](https://github.com/mono/maccore/pull/30). The code is now as :

```
NSString normalizedPath = new NSString (currentPath).StringByStandardizingPath ().StringByResolvingSymlinksInPath ();
```

Comment: Im also facing similar issue when using System.IO.Path.GetTempPath ().Where does this code point to?